# How to generate grid x,y coordinates

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple game, in the game I have a 4 x 4 square, what i would like to do is generate coordinate points to fill up the square with a 2.0 spacing.

I tried to do it but i got stuck and confused here:

```
var coords = []
for (var i = 0.2; i < 2; i += 0.4) {
  //round to 1dp
  coords.push(Math.round(i * 10) / 10)
}

console.log(coords)
```

I need to fill up the square like a Cartesian plane where the values increase by 0.2, until it reaches 1.8 to the left, top, right and bottom of the square

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: Why are you rounding, 0.2 + 0.4 is never going to overflow into multiple decimal places.

Comment: Are you using canvas to generate that grid or HTML elements?

Comment: I just need to generate the coordinates

Comment: Just asking for the way to show the results.

Comment: I will using them in a game engine

Comment: You want negative values too? Or just positive, where 0 is the center?

Comment: yes exactly just like the way the x/y plane is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go. I hope that's what you were asking for.

```js
var coords = [[], []];
const x = 0;
const y = 1;

/*
  Generate X coords
*/
for (var i = -1.8; i < 2; i += 0.4) {
  let c = Math.round(i * 10) / 10;
  coords[x].push(c);
  if(c + 0.2 == 0) coords[x].push(0);
}

/*
  Generate Y coords
*/
for (var i = -1.8; i < 2; i += 0.4) {
  let c = Math.round(i * 10) / 10;
  coords[y].push(c);
  if(c + 0.2 == 0) coords[y].push(0);
}

console.log(coords);
```

Comment: That was helpful but what i need is a bit different here i made the question more clear https://stackoverflow.com/q/54007719/5008598

Comment: This is the same question with the same problem. My code can solve your problem, just change values.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the other question, and this is what i needed thank you.